# Pull request procedure for hot fixes with tag-based release flow

Tags: git

My project's production is released from master branch and for each release the tag is created. 
From time to time hot fixes are required between releases, so the current practice is to branch from tag and then release from this new branch.

The problem is that there is a gap between actual tag and new branch which is not covered with any tools: as a reviewer you have to either rely on developer and believe that he has created branch from the right tag etc. (which was common practice so far) or you have to manually check where does the branch come from which is just another manual operation and can be skipped due to close deadlines.

**So the question is: is there any way to use pull requests procedure?** 
I would prefer raising pull request (or some similar control and review tool) to tags directly but as far as I understand I can't.
Also I can create prod-branch for each release and tag from it, but is seems ponderous to me and I would like to avoid such procedure.

P.S. Project uses Stash for pullrequests and Crucible for review.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`git branch --contains <last release tag>` will tell you what branches are branched off the last release.  If your hotfix branch isn't in that list, it wasn't made correctly.  You can that command to your hotfix release process.

This is even easier if you have a `latest` tag for the latest release.  Then it's just `git branch --contains latest`.  I would also recommend you name the hotfix branch consistently, like `hotfix`.  Delete it once it's deployed so nobody is tempted to use it after the fact, and so it can be used again for another hotfix.  Put a release tag in its place.

```
git branch --contains latest | grep hotfix
```